# How to login with non-root user on crouton Chromebook

Tags: login, chromebook, crouton

I recently bought a Chromebook and followed the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xsqrQw1kbs) to install Ubuntu via crouton.

Once I logged into Ubuntu I logged out again, which brought me back to the chromeOS.

I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the command screen, but don't know how to log back in with the username I created.

I have been running these commands to log in

```
sudo enter-chroot
sudo startxfce4
```

But this logs me in as root, which isn't ideal since I want to use Chromium browser.

I have no GUI to log in either and Chrome keeps starting in developer mode.

I have been searching and reading for hours and everything tells me how to log in as Root/Superuser which is the opposite of what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

`startxfce4` starts XFCE as the user you run it as - root in this case.

To use GUI login, you have to install a display manager. For Xfce4 I believe it's LightDM.

Comment: I am very new to this so bear with me.  On the terminal in the chromeOS what do I type in? I did sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and it ran and I restarted and it still comes to the same screen.  I am way over my head with this.  All I was trying to do was install a NES emulator and download some ROMs.  I have the emulator just need the ROMs but cant open chromium browser because im logged in as root.

Comment: Can't answer this - never used chromeOS.

Comment: I had the same issue with using chrome/chromium in the chroot. While not a solution, you could `sudo apt-get install firefox` and just use firefox?

Comment: I reset the device and am trying it over.  It's not a good idea to surf the web as root from what I read, which is why chromuim blocks you from opening it while logged in as root

Comment: I believe I am going to run into the same issue once I turn off the device.